# Remove Docker's PPA repository

Tags: apt, ppa, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL so using the PPA Gui isn't a possibility. I added the Docker PPA with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

And I'm able to see it with this command:

```
$ apt policy
```

relevant lines:

```
500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=bionic,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
```

But how can I remove this repository without GUI access? I've tried various permutations of:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ABC/DEF
```

with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove NAME_OF_PPA
```

If you need to search your software sources lists to see what PPA's you currently have active:

```
grep -r -i ppa /etc/apt/
```

Next, you can open any link starting with “http://ppa.launchpad.net” and find the exact PPA name you need.

Refresh the package manager’s information:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, remove the package and its dependencies with:

```
sudo apt autoremove NAME_OF_PACKAGE
```

After you enter this command, pay close attention to the list of packages that will be removed. If you see something you need in that list, then use the remove option of apt (instead of autoremove):

```
sudo apt remove NAME_OF_PACKAGE
```

Comment: how do I find the name of NAME_OF_PPA? (that's the crux of the question)

Comment: @philshem I've amended my answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually remove entries from this file, with sudo/root:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: I'll accept an answer with `apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ABC/DEF`

Answer (score 1):

@philshem If you want to remove entries manually, you have to keep in mind that `/etc/apt/sources.list` isn't necessarily the only file containing entries. There might be some files in `/ets/apt/sources.list.d/` you'd want to inspect and remove as needed.